# "Scoped" service's constructor getting called more than once

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, blazor

We have Blazor application where we are configuring a service with lifetime scope set to "Scoped". For some reason, this service's constructor is getting called more than once. Does anyone know why?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddScoped<IProjectClient, ProjectClient>();
}
```

ProjectClient's constructor is getting called more than once. Any thoughts/pointers?

Comment: Scoped services are called per request (HTTP). Are you getting them called multiple times within the scope of a Web request? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#scoped

Comment: yes more than once per request.

Comment: Does "calling" happens when user executes some actions on the page?

Comment: How you check that constructor get called multiple times **per request**? How you recognise boundaries of one request?

Comment: Where is it injected?

Comment: I have a log statement inside constructor which is getting logged more than once. @MisterMagoo what do you mean by getting injected?

Comment: Blazor does not have well defined Scopes. Look up OwiningComponentBase and why it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is called twice, as you are using pre-rendering. Go to _Host.cshtml and set render-mode="ServerPrerendered" to render-mode="Server", and it would be called only once.

Comment: If I use "Server" as render-mode, HttpContext from dependency injected IHttpContextAccessor is always null. Why would that be?

Comment: It's not related to the rendering mode... You can't access the HttpContext in Blazor Server App ( needless to say in WebAssembly Apps) as it is not available. at least most of the time. This is due to the fact that communication between Server Blazor and its client-side is done with SignaleR. You shouldn't use IHttpContextAccessor.

Comment: we are using httpcontext only in blazor server-side client. if using ihttpcontextaccessor is out of question, how can we get the current logged in user name in blazor server-side client? any pointers? appreciate your replies.

Comment: Some clarification is needed here: Blazor Server App or Server-side Blazor are terms used to describe the application that is executed on the server. WebAssembly App or client-side Blazor is a Blazor App that is executed on the client; that is, the browser. When I say  "Server Blazor and its client-side",  client-side stands for the browser. To be more exact, I refer to the Html document displayed on the screen, and the JavaScript SignaleR code that communicate with your Blazor server-side app that resides on the server.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. we are using httpcontext from Server-side Blazor. interestingly we get correct httpcontext in the first request but for all subsequent requests it is null. all we want to do is store current windows logged-in user's name (HttpContext.User.Identity.Name) into a variable and pass it to a service. just curious, how am i able to access httpcontext the first time?

Comment: You code only within the domain of your Asp.Net Core app that can run only on the server. Thus, saying "we are using httpcontext only in blazor server-side client" is wrong. Having said that... I can't answer your question without knowing how you log in your users. Do you use the Identity UI framework to authenticate your users, or perhaps you use Jwt authentication, the better advise you get from me will depend on the amount of information you provide about your app, authentication and authorization methods you want to use,

Comment: is it going to be a private or public web site, etc. Please, create a new question thread for this, and I'll be glad to help...

Comment: @biostat, I've already told you that HttpContext is not available with Blazor Server App, and with windows authentication the issue is worse as the HttpContext changes within the scope of a single SignaleR connection... The user name may change after you've read it, in the very same connection. I'll post here, if I find, a github issue, dealing with this, and suggestion by Steve Andreson how to cope.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12601#issuecomment-525804729   https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/14974  https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13903 https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/543

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/11633

Comment: I have set it to render mode Server in .net core 3.1 Blazor and it is instanced twice one in ConfigureServices and second inside the default AddScoped func. Any other change I've to make?  <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server"